# Pass parameter to another intent without followup question

Tags: python, flask, dialogflow-es

I am using dialogflow with python (library: flask_dialogflow) backend to create a chatbot. So I have an intent drive.read with a followup intent drive.read.yes containing a required paramater: "path". I have another intent transform.word2pdf with a followup intent transform.word2pdf.yes also containing a required paramater: "word_path". The conversation starts from drive.read and then drive.read.yes asks to fill the parameter "path" from the user. After filling that up, transform.word2pdf intent triggers and then transform.word2pdf.yes according to the flow of the conversation.

Now I want to pass the "path" value from drive.read.yes to the transform.word2pdf.yes parameter "word_path" if it exists. Also, if it exists, then the followup prompt about the path filling should not be asked by the bot since the word_path has already been filled up from the previous conversation in the different intent.

How should I pass the path parameter to another intent without followup prompt? Should I enter something in the intent's default value? If so, what exactly will be format? like #xxx.path? Right now, nothing exists in the value or default value of any intent and I didnt add any extra input/output contexts other than already created by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters between intents using contexts. You can set an output context in the drive.read.yes intent with the path parameter value and then set an input context in the transform.word2pdf.yes intent with the same name as the output context of the previous intent. This way, the transform.word2pdf.yes intent will be triggered only if the output context of drive.read.yes is active and you can access the path parameter value in transform.word2pdf.yes intent using $path parameter.
 
Regarding your second question, you can use a conditional statement to check if the word_path parameter exists in transform.word2pdf.yes intent. If it exists, you can skip the follow-up prompt about path filling by setting a context that indicates that the word_path parameter has already been filled up.